# Difference between interact, expect and exit in expect script

Tags: linux, expect

I have a expect script as follow.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

spawn "some_script.sh"

expect "Enter Auth Username:"
send "username\n"

expect "Enter Auth Password:"
send "password\n"

expect/interact/exit
```

I would like to know what is different between using expect/interact/exit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit` does what you think it does: exit the script immediately

`interact` returns control to the human: if there are things to enter manually after the script gives the auth user and passwd, the human must enter them.

`expect` watches the spawned process for patterns, and when a pattern is matched the script proceeds to the next instruction.

Comment: So is `expect` also exit after patterns are finished? So what will be different between exit and expect? Thanks!

Comment: Like any scripting language, when you run out of instructions the script will exit